# Добавление числа в отсортированный по убыванию массив не нарушая порядка

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка, insert

Вот так вот я заполняю массив но к сожалению никак не могу придумать как вставить в него число не сбивая порядка(что бы после вставки числа в массив порядок чисел не сбивался)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Creating array
    int a[N];
    int i, j, temp;

    printf("Enter size of array\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    printf("Enter number to create array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    //Sorting the array ascending descending
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        temp = a[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            if (temp > a[j]) {
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
              a[j] = temp;
            }
    }
    //Output of sorted array
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для начала необходимо найти позицию, в которую будем вставлять новое значение. Так как массив упорядочен, то лучше воспользоваться алгоритмом бинарного поиска.

После того, как позиция для вставки найдена, необходимо сместить все элементы, начиная с найденной позиции на один элемент "вправо".

Теперь всё готово к записи нового значения в найденную позицию.

Comment: Точно, можно ещё добавить *man memmove*.